# Dar de alta un fichero en mysql con php sin repetir

Tags: php, mysql, archivo

tengo el siguiente ejercicio. Tengo que dar de alta un fichero de texto tiene la siguiente forma:
[image: TEXTO]

En el se diferencia el código de cliente, el nombre y la edad en distintas líneas. Ese fichero tengo que darlo de alta en una DB sin repetir el código.

Mi idea es leerlo y almacenarlo en un array utilizando de índice el código para que no almacenar los repetidos.

Pero no se me ocurre la manera de saltar las líneas cuando encuentro uno repetido.

Este es el trozo de codigo que tengo. (SOLO INTENTO ALMACENARLO EN EL ARRAY)

```
<?php
$fichero = fopen('clientes.txt', 'rb');
    if (!$fichero){
        echo "Ha habido algun problema al intentar abrir el fichero";
    }else{
        $n = 0;
        while(!feof($fichero)){
            $linea = fgets($fichero);
            $linea = trim($linea,"\r\n");
            if($n === 3){
                $n = 0;
            }
            if($linea != null){
                if(!isset($array[$linea][$n])){
                    $array[$linea][$n] = $linea
                    $n++;
                }
            }

        }

    }

    //fclose($_FILES['objetofile1']['name']);
    fclose($fichero);
```

?>

Esto no funciona claro porque no se como diferenciar la línea que es código de las demás...

Comment: Tienes que buscar una lógica para hacer trabajar tu código. En este caso la lógica que aplicaría es que *los códigos estarán **después de cada cuarta línea***. Entonces, ve contando desde el principio: la 1ª línea del fichero es un código ... líneas 2, 3, 4 ... siguiente línea será otro código ... reinicia contador ... líneas 2, 3, 4, siguiente línea será el otro código ... etc.

Comment: En fin, muchísimas gracias, lo he resuelto con el contador que dices. Era lo que estaba pensando pero no conseguía verlo... GRACIAAS!!!!

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIONADO:

```
<?php

    $fichero = fopen('clientes.txt', 'rb');
    if (!$fichero){
        echo "Ha habido algun problema al intentar abrir el fichero";
    }else{
        $n = 0;
        while(!feof($fichero)){
            $linea = fgets($fichero);
            $linea = trim($linea,"\r\n");
            if($n === 0){
                $codigo = $linea;
            }
            if($linea != null){
                if(!isset($array[$codigo][$n])){
                    
                    $array[$codigo][$n] = $linea;
                    echo $array[$codigo][$n]."<br>";
                    
                }
                $n++;
            }else{
                $n = 0;
            }

        }

    

    fclose($fichero);
```

?>

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).